# display error message when connection lost

Tags: php

I have form and I'm using it to echo some currencies...

basically, I'm using file_get_contents() function and if I lose connection I get this error :

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   in

is it possible to echo some custom error? when the user loses his connection while trying to submit the form..

my php code :

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

<?php
$params = $_REQUEST;
//print_R($params);die('fff');
if(isset($params) && isset($params['amount']) && isset($params['from']) && isset($params['from'])) {
    currencyConverter($params['from'], $params['to'], $params['amount']);
}

function currencyConverter($from_currency,$to_currency,$amount) {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_currency = urlencode($from_currency);
    $to_currency = urlencode($to_currency);
    $get = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_currency&to=$to_currency");
    $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
    $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
    $converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);

    echo $converted_currency;

    if($from_currency == $to_currency){


      echo "try again";
    }


}
```

Comment: When *user loses his connection* on their device or when the server `file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com ...` fails ?

Comment: you could hide the error by using `@file_get_contents()` and then check if `$get` matches your requirements and if not, post an error.

Comment: @BNT adding "@" helped me a lot .. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably catch the error on the `file_get_contents` function. It returns false on failure.
Here is the documentation for it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$get = @file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_currency&to=$to_currency");
if(!$get){
   echo "My custom error";
}
```

Comment: using @file_get_contents + the if statment worked for me ! thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped, I will add the @ to my answer